# Assert true, variable from two methods

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests

Website: http://automationpractice.com/ 
Login: testingTest@gmail.com 
Pass: testtest

I'm trying to automate process of buying clothes.

The problem is:

I have tabs to finish process I need to go through every tabs.
Address|Added Products|Terms and conditions| Pay by|Payment| Summary|
I'd like to get Total Price from from "Added Products" tab and then get Total Price from Summary and by Assert True check if they are the same.

```
@FindBy(id = "total_price")
private WebElement totalPriceOfOrder;


@FindBy(id = "total_price")
private WebElement totalPriceOfOrder;


public void checkTotalValueOfOrderInSummaryTab(){
    String orderPrice = totalPriceOfOrder.getText();
}


@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/span")
private WebElement getPriceWhenOrderIsPaid;` 

public void getLastPrice(){
    String priceIsPaid = getPriceWhenOrderIsPaid.getText();
}
```

When I'm trying to assert this method I get error that it's impossible to find total_price element. Of course that this is impossible because I'm on different tab when checking it.

So how to fix it? How to Assign price from first method to variable and assert it to price from second method?

Comment: Please for the love of everything holy, never post a password of any kind on to the internet

Comment: This is a random testing site and user don't has any permissions

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to have your Get method return the value so that your script can store it and use it later.

For example, change your `getLastPrice()` method to return the price (`String`)

```
public String getLastPrice(){
    return getPriceWhenOrderIsPaid.getText();
}
```

then in your script you would store the returned value to do an assert later, e.g.

```
String price = getLastPrice();
Assert.areEqual(totalPriceOfOrder.getText(), price, "Verify price");
```

NOTE: I don't know which variables you have posted are which, I just grabbed a couple and used them as an example.

Comment: still: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#total_price"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: Your question wasn't about fixing your locators, it was about a method to compare prices on two pages. I've shown that method in this answer. If you have a problem with locators, you probably need to do some research and see if you can figure it out on your own. If you can't solve it yourself, post a new question.

Comment: I don't have problem with locator because when i change method to `public void checkTotalValueOfOrderInSummaryTab() {
        String totalPrice= totalPriceOfOrder.getText();
        System.out.println(totalPrice); ` i get result without error   [Link to project without modification from this post]  (https://github.com/bubsk/ShopTEST/blob/master/src/test/java/page/objects/ShoppingProcessPages.java)

Answer (score 0):

```
@FindBy(id = "total_price")
private WebElement totalPriceOfOrder;

@FindBy(xpath = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/span")
private WebElement getPriceWhenOrderIsPaid;
```

`public String checkTotalValueOfOrderInSummaryTab() {
    return totalPriceOfOrder.getText();
}`

```
public void getLastPrice() {
String PriceWhenOrderIsPaid = getPriceWhenOrderIsPaid.getText();
String price = checkTotalValueOfOrderInSummaryTab();
Assert.assertEquals(getPriceWhenOrderIsPaid.getText(), price, "Verify price");}
```

Comment: This is not an answer... did you mean to edit your question and add this?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange,

Because. You have an error. I think that you have to see if your element is inside in a iframe If so... apply this

driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");